# Why doesn't this CSS animation work in IE10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFavB/) contains a CSS animation that works for me in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not IE 10. I know IE 10 [doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453858.aspx) [need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh772212.aspx) the `-ms-` prefix, so that can't be it. I can't see anything wrong with this:

```
@keyframes snapVertical {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  16% { background-position: 0 0; }
  21% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  37% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  42% { background-position: 0 -272px; }
  58% { background-position: 0 -272px; }
  63% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  79% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  84% { background-position: 0 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
.animation-snap-vertical {
  animation: snapVertical 4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) 0s infinite;
}
```

Why doesn't this work in IE 10?

**EDIT**

Why does the horizontal one work, but not the vertical ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFavB/1/))?

Horizontal animation:

```
@keyframes snapHorizontal {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  16% { background-position: 0 0; }
  21% { background-position: -176px 0; }
  37% { background-position: -176px 0; }
  42% { background-position: -352px 0; }
  58% { background-position: -352px 0; }
  63% { background-position: -176px 0; }
  79% { background-position: -176px 0;}
  84% { background-position: 0 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
.animation-snap-horizontal {
  animation: snapHorizontal 4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) 0s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in IE (see [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218265/css-background-image-sprite-position-transition-goes-in-different-direction-in-i)). To get around this, I simply changed the initial and final offsets to 0.1px instead of 0. This seems to have solved the problem. The solution code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFavB/2/)):

```
@keyframes snapVertical {
  0% { background-position: 0 0.1px; }
  16% { background-position: 0 0.1px; }
  21% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  37% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  42% { background-position: 0 -272px; }
  58% { background-position: 0 -272px; }
  63% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  79% { background-position: 0 -136px; }
  84% { background-position: 0 0.1px; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0.1px; }
}
.animation-snap-vertical {
  animation: snapVertical 4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) 0s infinite;
}
```