# IE 9 and 10 background-position

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, background-position

I'm animating a squared sprite (n lines x m columns) with animation keyframes and background-image property. It works fine on Chrome, FF and Safari but it's totally broken on IE 9 and 10.

Here a bit of CSS (with SASS):

```
include keyframes(animation) {
    @for $i from 0 through 45 {
        $line : floor($i/9);
        $col : $i%9;
        $s : 20.03+($i * 14)/45 + "%";
        @if $i != 45 { #{$s}{background-position: ($col * -163px) ($line * -107px);};}
    }
}
```

How can I fix this on IE ?

Comment: What does the resulting CSS look like? Can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: I can't put a fiddle. It looks like x or y is not called. The result is a very jerky animation.

Comment: @MrLister here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kn6uD/

Comment: +1 to question since the complete answer isn't as simple as one would suspect. IE10 apparently has a very specific bug with `background-position` and CSS3 animations. It also has another very specific bug related to `background-position` which is not the issue with this question, but I will link to it since it may help someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053703/rare-ie10-bug-css-animation-of-background-position-fails-with-multiple-backgrou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally broken in IE9, because it does not support CSS3 animations:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx#animations

It's broken in IE10 for two reasons:

1. Because you're not supposed to use the `-ms-` prefix for animation properties in IE10 and above:

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh772212.aspx
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh772747.aspx
2. Because IE10 has a bug where it doesn't use `0` values for `background-position` correctly in animations:

   - [Why doesn't this CSS animation work in IE10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280791/why-doesnt-this-css-animation-work-in-ie10)

To fix part 2, you can use a value close to `0` like `0.1`.

**Thus use this CSS instead:**

```
#ball {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/pKnpIzd.png');
  width: 133px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 280px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: ball 10s infinite ; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: step-start; 
  animation: ball 10s infinite ; 
  animation-timing-function: step-start; 
}

/* WEBKIT VERSION */

@-webkit-keyframes ball {
  16% { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  16.49296% { background-position: -133px 0px; }
  16.98592% { background-position: -266px 0px; }
  17.47887% { background-position: -399px 0px; }
  17.97183% { background-position: -532px 0px; }
  18.46479% { background-position: -665px 0px; }
  18.95775% { background-position: -798px 0px; }
  19.4507% { background-position: -931px 0px; }
  19.94366% { background-position: 0px -170px; }
  20.43662% { background-position: -133px -170px; }
  20.92958% { background-position: -266px -170px; }
  21.42254% { background-position: -399px -170px; }
  21.91549% { background-position: -532px -170px; }
  22.40845% { background-position: -665px -170px; }
  22.90141% { background-position: -798px -170px; }
  23.39437% { background-position: -931px -170px; }
  23.88732% { background-position: 0px -340px; }
  24.38028% { background-position: -133px -340px; }
  24.87324% { background-position: -266px -340px; }
  25.3662% { background-position: -399px -340px; }
  25.85915% { background-position: -532px -340px; }
  26.35211% { background-position: -665px -340px; }
  26.84507% { background-position: -798px -340px; }
  27.33803% { background-position: -931px -340px; }
  27.83099% { background-position: 0px -510px; }
  28.32394% { background-position: -133px -510px; }
  28.8169% { background-position: -266px -510px; }
  29.30986% { background-position: -399px -510px; }
  29.80282% { background-position: -532px -510px; }
  30.29577% { background-position: -665px -510px; }
  30.78873% { background-position: -798px -510px; }
  31.28169% { background-position: -931px -510px; }
  31.77465% { background-position: 0px -680px; }
  32.26761% { background-position: -133px -680px; }
  32.76056% { background-position: -266px -680px; }
  33.25352% { background-position: -399px -680px; }
  33.74648% { background-position: -532px -680px; }
  34.23944% { background-position: -665px -680px; }
  34.73239% { background-position: -798px -680px; }
  35.22535% { background-position: -931px -680px; }
  35.71831% { background-position: 0px -850px; }
  36.21127% { background-position: -133px -850px; }
  36.70423% { background-position: -266px -850px; }
  37.19718% { background-position: -399px -850px; }
  37.69014% { background-position: -532px -850px; }
  38.1831% { background-position: -665px -850px; }
  38.67606% { background-position: -798px -850px; }
  39.16901% { background-position: -931px -850px; }
  39.66197% { background-position: 0px -1020px; }
  40.15493% { background-position: -133px -1020px; }
  40.64789% { background-position: -266px -1020px; }
  41.14085% { background-position: -399px -1020px; }
  41.6338% { background-position: -532px -1020px; }
  100% { background-position: -532px -1020px; }
}

/* STANDARDS-COMPLIANT VERSION */

@keyframes ball { 
  16% { background-position: 0.1px 0.1px; }
  16.49296% { background-position: -133px 0.1px; }
  16.98592% { background-position: -266px 0.1px; }
  17.47887% { background-position: -399px 0.1px; }
  17.97183% { background-position: -532px 0.1px; }
  18.46479% { background-position: -665px 0.1px; }
  18.95775% { background-position: -798px 0.1px; }
  19.4507% { background-position: -931px 0.1px; }
  19.94366% { background-position: 0.1px -170px; }
  20.43662% { background-position: -133px -170px; }
  20.92958% { background-position: -266px -170px; }
  21.42254% { background-position: -399px -170px; }
  21.91549% { background-position: -532px -170px; }
  22.40845% { background-position: -665px -170px; }
  22.90141% { background-position: -798px -170px; }
  23.39437% { background-position: -931px -170px; }
  23.88732% { background-position: 0.1px -340px; }
  24.38028% { background-position: -133px -340px; }
  24.87324% { background-position: -266px -340px; }
  25.3662% { background-position: -399px -340px; }
  25.85915% { background-position: -532px -340px; }
  26.35211% { background-position: -665px -340px; }
  26.84507% { background-position: -798px -340px; }
  27.33803% { background-position: -931px -340px; }
  27.83099% { background-position: 0.1px -510px; }
  28.32394% { background-position: -133px -510px; }
  28.8169% { background-position: -266px -510px; }
  29.30986% { background-position: -399px -510px; }
  29.80282% { background-position: -532px -510px; }
  30.29577% { background-position: -665px -510px; }
  30.78873% { background-position: -798px -510px; }
  31.28169% { background-position: -931px -510px; }
  31.77465% { background-position: 0.1px -680px; }
  32.26761% { background-position: -133px -680px; }
  32.76056% { background-position: -266px -680px; }
  33.25352% { background-position: -399px -680px; }
  33.74648% { background-position: -532px -680px; }
  34.23944% { background-position: -665px -680px; }
  34.73239% { background-position: -798px -680px; }
  35.22535% { background-position: -931px -680px; }
  35.71831% { background-position: 0.1px -850px; }
  36.21127% { background-position: -133px -850px; }
  36.70423% { background-position: -266px -850px; }
  37.19718% { background-position: -399px -850px; }
  37.69014% { background-position: -532px -850px; }
  38.1831% { background-position: -665px -850px; }
  38.67606% { background-position: -798px -850px; }
  39.16901% { background-position: -931px -850px; }
  39.66197% { background-position: 0.1px -1020px; }
  40.15493% { background-position: -133px -1020px; }
  40.64789% { background-position: -266px -1020px; }
  41.14085% { background-position: -399px -1020px; }
  41.6338% { background-position: -532px -1020px; }
  100% { background-position: -532px -1020px; } 
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/5LKYF/4/)

Comment: That's weird because your exemple works but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I have fixed the issue where it works once in IE10, then upon refreshing it breaks and becomes choppy. The answer has been updated. The issue is that IE10 does not understand how to use `0` values properly in the `background-position` during an animation (for whatever buggy reason).

Comment: Just a general comment: I'd like to mention that IE has problems with the 0 values in a lot of cases. Sometimes, "margin: 0 auto" doesn't work properly in IE because it doesn't count the 0 as "0px". It may be a good habit to write "0" as "0px" when it is meant as that.